# How to run a program and kill the program using pipes

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have an interactive command line program that produces text when it is run. What I want to do is run the program, extract text via perl regex, and then kill the program.

```
/path/to/my/program | perl regex magic
```

So far I have the line above. It starts the program and extracts text from the progam's output. The problem is that after I extract the text, the /path/to/my/program keeps running. I need to kill that process because I no longer need this. I want my line to look like the line below:

```
/path/to/my/program | perl regex magic | terminate original process
```

where original process is the process created by running /path/to/my/program

**TLDR;**
How do I start a process and kill it in the same line with bash?

I've tried simulating the input of the program to be control-c (ascii 0x3) but it literally inputs "^C" instead of simulating me physically pressing control c on my keyboard.

Comment: Pipe are asynchronous; both `program` and `perl` run at the same time, not one after the other. Your third component would *also* start at the same time, likely killing your program before it has a chance to do anything. A pipe is not the answer here.

Comment: ^C is not input to any of the programs; your *terminal* intercepts that and interprets it as a request to send `SIGINT` to each process in the current foreground process group.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you know it is time for killing the process. If a given period is enough then you can:

```
timeout 30 /path/to/my/program | perl regex magic
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without timeout? That command is not available by default on Mac and yes I know I can install it but I am building a tool and I do not want it to have any dependencies.

Comment: @andermoran: `/path/to/my/program & sleep 30s; kill $!`

Comment: Note those three commands would all have to be executed in a command group , since both `&` and `;` terminate a pipeline. `{ program & sleep 30s; kill $!; } | perl ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  perl regex magic $line
  if <condition to kill>; then
    killall command
  fi
done< <(command)
```

This will read the output of the program line by line and allow you to insert your code every time that a line prints. You can decide somewhere in the logic inside of the while loop when/how you want to exit. This isn't pipes but.......